# connect to db after creating connection nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have created a connection in nodejs file.

```
var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: obj.host,
  user: obj.user,
  password: obj.password,
  port: obj.port //Always mention port number
});
```

after this I have created a database.

```
con.query("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS cart", function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Database created")
```

I want to refer to this database using the same connection. For Example:

```
con.database: 'cart';
```

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested SQL query to connect to the database;

```
con.query("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS cart;", function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Database created")
    con.query('USE cart;', function (error, results) {
        if (error) throw error;
        console.log('Database connected');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you got to add to - database: "cart" like this:

```
var con = mysql.createConnection({
      host: obj.host,
      user: obj.user,
      password: obj.password,
      port: obj.port //Always mention port number
      database: "cart"
    });
```